# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Hi After three days of browsing, debugging i couldn't find the reason of the error

I created database using SQLite DB Browser extension - firefox
I added in my assets (but its showing a question mark in the icon to the left of the DB name in ndroid studio.)

After days of browsing i tried changing the version, changing db name, extension, tried changing the "**this.getReadableDatabase();**" to"**this.getWriteableDatabase();**" vice versa..

But still I am getting the mentioned error some one guide me.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jalil.justquiz/com.jalil.justquiz.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: quiz_title (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT quiz_title FROM quiz_title WHERE _id = 1
```

**My databaseHelper:**

```
    package com.jalil.justquiz;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStream;

   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.SQLException;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

   /*
    * Created by Jalil on 14-11-2015.
    */
   public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static String DATABASE_NAME = "";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

private static final String QUIZ_USER_DETAILS_TABLE = "quiz_user_details";
private static final String COLUMN_USERCOUNT = "User_Count";
private static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "User_Name";
private static final String COLUMN_USRID = "User_Id";
private static final String COLUMN_USERSCORE = "User_Score";

private static final String QUIZ_TITLE_TABLE = "quiz_title";
private static final String COLUMN_QUIZTITLEID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_QUIZTITLE = "quiz_title";


private static final String QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE = "quiz_question";
private static final String COLUMN_QUESTION_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_QUESTION_TITLE_ID = "quiz_title_id";
private static final String COLUMN_QUESTION = "quiz_question";
private static final String COLUMN_QUESTION_ANSWERED = "quiz_question_answered";
private static final String COLUMN_QUESTION_ANSWERED_CORRECT = "quiz_question_answered_correct";


private static final String QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE = "quiz_option";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION_QUESTION_ID = "quiz_question_id";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION_1 = "quiz_option_1";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION_2 = "quiz_option_2";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION_3 = "quiz_option_3";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION_4 = "quiz_option_4";
private static final String COLUMN_CORRECT_OPTION = "quiz_correct_option";


   //    private static final String QUIZ_USER_ANSWER_TABLE = "quiz_user_answer";
   //    private static final String QUIZ_USER_ANSWER__ID = "quiz_user_answer";
   //    private static final String QUIZ_USER_ANSWER__OPTION = "quiz_option_id";


private SQLiteDatabase database;

private final Context context;

// database path
private static String DATABASE_PATH;

/** constructor */
public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context ctx,String databaseName)  {
    super(ctx, databaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    DATABASE_NAME = databaseName;
    this.context = ctx;
    //DATABASE_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath() ;
    DATABASE_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void create() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db.isOpen()){
            db.close();
        }
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

/** open the database */
public void open() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

/** close the database */
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null)
        database.close();
    super.close();
}

//region User Detail Table
// insert a user into the database
public long insert_QUIZ_USER_DETAILS(int usrCount, String usrName, int userId,int userScore) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_USERCOUNT, usrCount);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, usrName);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_USRID, userId);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_USERSCORE, userScore);
    return database.insert(QUIZ_USER_DETAILS_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// updates a user
public boolean update_QUIZ_USER_DETAILS(int rowId,int usrCount, String usrName, int userId,int userScore) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_USERCOUNT, usrCount);
    args.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, usrName);
    args.put(COLUMN_USRID, userId);
    args.put(COLUMN_USERSCORE, userScore);
    return database.update(QUIZ_USER_DETAILS_TABLE, args, COLUMN_USRID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves a particular user
public Cursor get_QUIZ_USER_DETAILS(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, QUIZ_USER_DETAILS_TABLE, new String[] {
                      COLUMN_USERNAME, COLUMN_USRID, COLUMN_USERSCORE },
   //                        COLUMN_USERCOUNT, COLUMN_USERNAME, COLUMN_USRID, COLUMN_USERSCORE },
            COLUMN_USRID + " = " + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}

// delete a particular user
public boolean delete_SELECTED_QUIZ_USER_DETAILS(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(QUIZ_USER_DETAILS_TABLE, COLUMN_USRID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves all users
public Cursor getAll_QUIZ_USER_DETAILS() {
    return database.query(QUIZ_USER_DETAILS_TABLE, new String[] {
                    COLUMN_USERNAME, COLUMN_USRID, COLUMN_USERSCORE }, null, null,
   //                COLUMN_USERCOUNT,COLUMN_USERNAME, COLUMN_USRID, COLUMN_USERSCORE }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}
//endregion


//region Quiz Title
// insert a quiz title
public long insert_QUIZ_TITLE(int quizTitleId, String quizTitle) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUIZTITLEID, quizTitleId);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUIZTITLE, quizTitle);
    return database.insert(QUIZ_TITLE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// updates a quiz title
public boolean update_QUIZ_TITLE(int rowId,int quizTitleId, String quizTitle) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_QUIZTITLEID, quizTitleId);
    args.put(COLUMN_QUIZTITLE, quizTitle);
    return database.update(QUIZ_TITLE_TABLE, args, COLUMN_QUIZTITLEID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves a quiz title
public Cursor get_QUIZ_TITLE(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, QUIZ_TITLE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    COLUMN_QUIZTITLE,  },
            COLUMN_QUIZTITLEID + " = " + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}

// delete a particular quiz title
public boolean delete_SELECTED_QUIZ_TITLE(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(QUIZ_TITLE_TABLE, COLUMN_QUIZTITLEID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves all quiz titles
public Cursor getAll_QUIZ_TITLE() {
    return database.query(QUIZ_TITLE_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_QUIZTITLE }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}
//endregion


//region Quiz Question
// insert a quiz Question
public long insert_QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE(int quizQuestionId,int quizQuestionTitleId, String quizQuestion,int quizAnswered,int quizAnsweredCorct) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_ID, quizQuestionId);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_TITLE_ID, quizQuestionTitleId);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUESTION, quizQuestion);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_ANSWERED, quizAnswered);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_ANSWERED_CORRECT, quizAnsweredCorct);
    return database.insert(QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// updates a quiz Question
public boolean update_QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE(long rowId,int quizQuestionId,int quizQuestionTitleId, String quizQuestion,int quizAnswered,int quizAnsweredCorct) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_ID, quizQuestionId);
    args.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_TITLE_ID, quizQuestionId);
    args.put(COLUMN_QUESTION, quizQuestion);
    args.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_ANSWERED, quizAnswered);
    args.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_ANSWERED_CORRECT, quizAnsweredCorct);
    return database.update(QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE, args, COLUMN_QUESTION_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves a quiz Question
public Cursor get_QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE, new String[] {
                    COLUMN_QUESTION_TITLE_ID,COLUMN_QUESTION,COLUMN_QUESTION_ANSWERED,COLUMN_QUESTION_ANSWERED_CORRECT  },
            COLUMN_QUESTION_ID + " = " + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}

// delete a particular quiz Question
public boolean delete_SELECTED_QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE, COLUMN_QUESTION_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves all quiz Questions
public Cursor getAll_QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE() {
    return database.query(QUIZ_QUESTION_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_QUESTION }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}
//endregion


//region Quiz Options
// insert quiz Options
public long insert_QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE(int quizOptionId,int quizQuestionId, String quizOption_1, String quizOption_2, String quizOption_3, String quizOption_4,int quizCorrectOption) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_OPTION_ID, quizOptionId);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_OPTION_QUESTION_ID, quizQuestionId);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_OPTION_1, quizOption_1);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_OPTION_2, quizOption_2);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_OPTION_3, quizOption_3);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_OPTION_4, quizOption_4);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_CORRECT_OPTION, quizCorrectOption);
    return database.insert(QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// updates a quiz Options
public boolean update_QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE(long rowId, int quizOptionId,int quizQuestionId, String quizOption_1, String quizOption_2, String quizOption_3, String quizOption_4,int quizCorrectOption) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_OPTION_ID, quizOptionId);
    args.put(COLUMN_OPTION_QUESTION_ID, quizQuestionId);
    args.put(COLUMN_OPTION_1, quizOption_1);
    args.put(COLUMN_OPTION_2, quizOption_2);
    args.put(COLUMN_OPTION_3, quizOption_3);
    args.put(COLUMN_OPTION_4, quizOption_4);
    args.put(COLUMN_CORRECT_OPTION, quizCorrectOption);
    return database.update(QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE, args, COLUMN_OPTION_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves a quiz Options
public Cursor get_QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE, new String[] {
                    COLUMN_OPTION_1,COLUMN_OPTION_2,COLUMN_OPTION_3, COLUMN_OPTION_4,COLUMN_CORRECT_OPTION  },
            COLUMN_OPTION_ID + " = " + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}

// delete a particular quiz Option
public boolean delete_SELECTED_QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE, COLUMN_OPTION_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves all quiz Option
public Cursor getAll_QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE() {
    return database.query(QUIZ_OPTION_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_QUESTION }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}
//endregion


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

   }
```

My MainActivity:

```
   package com.jalil.justquiz;       
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.SQLException;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DatabaseOpenHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this,"QUIZ_db.sqlite");
    try {
        // check if database exists in app path, if not copy it from assets
        myDbHelper.create();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        // open the database
        myDbHelper.open();
        myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    // retrieve a particular question
    Cursor c = myDbHelper.get_QUIZ_TITLE(1);
    Toast.makeText(this, "id: " + c.getInt(0) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    c.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**My Database:**

[image]

**My Logcat:**

```
    11-16 22:51:39.537  16947-16947/com.jalil.justquiz E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: quiz_title
    11-16 22:51:39.577  16947-16947/com.jalil.justquiz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jalil.justquiz, PID: 16947
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jalil.justquiz/com.jalil.justquiz.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: quiz_title (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT quiz_title FROM quiz_title WHERE _id = 1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: quiz_title (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT quiz_title FROM quiz_title WHERE _id = 1
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
        at com.jalil.justquiz.DatabaseOpenHelper.get_QUIZ_TITLE(DatabaseOpenHelper.java:230)
        at com.jalil.justquiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**   On opening the database from DDMS it seems only the android_metadata tabel is present in the database. Hence it *shows no such table*  but why is are the tables from database in 'assets' folder copied to the database in '/databases' folder

Comment: It looks like your not creating the table.  Double check to make sure you created it because your syntax is good  See if its throwing an I/O exception when you

Comment: Use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: shouldn't this getReadableDatabase() be getWriteableDatabase() in your create();

Comment: you database is missing very important table "android_metadata"

Comment: Hi @Jasz  I am pre creating the tabels using SQLite DB browser so my code checks if the database exists if not creates an empty database then copy the tabels from the database in the asset folder.
Also tried getWriteableDatabase() still same error.


--PankajNimgade-- i do have android_metadata its my very first table in my attached table list

Comment: Did you add <provider> in manifest?

Comment: No @Ajitha i havent added <provider> i am not aware of it. Also no idea as how to do it.

Comment: Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html